# ngx-admin add mapbox in new page component

Tags: angularjs, mapbox-gl-js, nebular, ngx-admin

how I want to add mapbox in `<nb-card-body>` in new pages i had created ?

I've already add html simple mapbox but nothing show on my mapsla page...

my component to add mapbox is mapsla and this project is based on ngx-admin starter-kit

[mapsla.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnS5D.png)

[mapsla.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn66f.png)

[mapsla.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djGQf.png)

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kpm2.png)

[screen shot Error in ngx-admin web browser , map not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Pb1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot insert `html` tag into the `nb-card-body` as html is a container element for other elements. Since ngx-admin is built on top of Angular, try using corresponding library https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much  .My map is showing in website now .